# Doctrine 2 Configuration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am a beginner in dealing with Doctrine. I went to their website and found version 2.0 (stable) which appeared to be the latest one. Installed it using PEAR method, though had some difficulties. The documentation seemed quite messy for me, however I searched over internet and found samples of the boostrap file. Documentation for Doctrine 2.0 may be found [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html)
.

`I did follow the instructions and included the class laoding file as with require_once ('libs/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php'); at the beginning.

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', 'libs');
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', 'libs');
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', 'libs');
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Dao', 'libs');
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache);
$config->setProxyDir('/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array("/Entities"));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

$connectionOptions = array(
'dbname' => 'db',
'user' => 'root',
'password' => 'mypassword',
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

// At this point no actual connection to the database is created
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionOptions);//('mysql:  //root:127.0.0.1@127.0.0.1/db');
// The first time the connection is needed, it is instantiated
// This query triggers the connection to be created
$conn->exec('SHOW TABLES');`
```

Found out that method "execute" is "exec" in version 2, and that you use DriverManager in version 2 instead of something else. Now, when I try to test if Doctrine works, it gives me no output and gives and error of unexpected T_STRING, which actually means that commands are not understood.

With version 1.2 there is a test with getPath(), but this function is not present in version 2.0, or maybe there is something else I am doing wrong. Note that $conn->exec does not do anything as well.

I run Windows 7 and the WAMP Server version 2, PHP 5.3.3. I out the folder with Doctrine in my project directory, though I do not really get what was the PEAR installation made for? is there a chance to use Doctrine without adding in to project directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to trigger the connection? It connects lazily when its first used. After the EntityManager::create method you should be good.

Comment: Doctrine connection problem please help me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856626/doctrine-2-0-select-query-problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say from how you've described the problem, but I suggest you to use a debugger such as one embedded in Zend Studio (or you can set Zend's up with any eclipse-based IDE such as Aptana). This will make things much more clear.