# Doctrine 2.0 select query problem?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

i friends i am new to DOctrine 2.0 .i already configure but it is not working ...

I have one table "`abctable`" in data base "`xyzdb`".

```
        id  name   age

        --------------
        1   Abc     23  
        2   Ijk     21
        3   Mno     32  
        -------------- 

Table name:abctable
db name:xyzdb
host    :127.0.0.1
dbusername:king
dbpassword:123456
```

In this above configuration .How to configure using doctrine 2.0 Version.

```
And how to use query --"select * from abctable" in Doctrine 2.0
```

version.Select ,insert,delect,update give one example..please help...

Comment: The best way to learn about something new is to read the documentation as Jeremy suggested. Also there's a [sandbox](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html#sandbox-quickstart) which you can adapt to your real application

Comment: i am already done getting connection problem....i need php 5.3.6 version configuration..

Comment: You say you already have a working connection? So that means you already have a EntityManager? Show us some code and tell us what is not working. This question is way to general!

Comment: ok .. doctrine  2.0.4 configuration difference .but i am start.geeting some errors.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878718/doctrine-2-0-4-configuration-problem

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the documentation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/, specifically the section on configuration http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html to get you started.

Comment: i am already done getting connection problem....i need php 5.3.6 version configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[Doctrine2 basic; Proxies, Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056440/doctrine2-basic-proxies-repositories/6056877#6056877)