# Doctrine 2.0.4 Configuration Error?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine 2.0.4 .i am not sure where exact wrong here any one can help here?

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache,
    Entities\User,Entity\Address;

$RootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';
require $RootPath.'doctrine2/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$lib = $RootPath.'doctrine2/';
$lib1 = $RootPath.'MyProject/';
$classLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine',$lib);
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new ClassLoader('Entities',$lib1);
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies',$lib1);
$classLoader->register();

$config = new Configuration;
$cache= new ApcCache;

$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($lib1.'Entities');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);


$config->setProxyDir($lib1.'Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('MyProject\Proxies');


 $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);


$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'user' => 'abc',
    'password' => '123321',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1');



$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($em);
// custom datatypes (not mapped for reverse engineering)
/*$em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('set', 'string');
$em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
*/

// fetch metadata
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver(
    $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
);
$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
$cmf = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory($em);
$cmf->setEntityManager($em); 
$classes = $driver->getAllClassNames();
$metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata(); 
$generator = new EntityGenerator();
$generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
$generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
$generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
$generator->generate($metadata, $lib1 . 'Entities');
echo  'Done';
$q = $em->createQuery("select u from MyProject\Entities\Dept u ");
$users = $q->getResult();
?>
```

Resulting in:

```
Error::Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'MyProject\Entities\Dept': Error: Class 'MyProject\Entities\Dept' is not defined.

Dept.php in Entities code

<?php


/**
 * Dept
 *
 * @Table(name="dept")
 * @Entity
 */
class Dept
{
    /**
     * @var integer $deptno
     *
     * @Column(name="deptno", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */

    private $deptno;

    /**
     * @var string $dname
     *
     * @Column(name="dname", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $dname;

    /**
     * @var string $location
     *
     * @Column(name="location", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $location;


    /**
     * Get deptno
     *
     * @return integer $deptno
     */
    public function getDeptno()
    {
        return $this->deptno;
    }

    /**
     * Set dname
     *
     * @param string $dname
     */
    public function setDname($dname)
    {
        $this->dname = $dname;
    }

    /**
     * Get dname
     *
     * @return string $dname
     */
    public function getDname()
    {
        return $this->dname;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string $location
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }
}
    and Proxies class not generated here but Entities is generated...where exact wrong here?
```

Comment: Proxies classes not genarated ..what i am doing now?

Comment: Your script would create any output, just an instance of the EntityManager. Add `var_dump($em);` to the bottom and tell me what happens.

Comment: Is your proxy folder writeable? I'm pretty sure Doctrine will only generate proxies as it needs them.

Comment: Entities generated now ,but proxies is not generated ...

Comment: Something is wrong with your namespace or directory. Have you tried `$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');`?

Comment: tried not use.but entities is generated ... if any problem in $lib1 ..please help me

Comment: I didn't ask "not use" ;) I said try to replace `MyProject\Proxies` with `Proxies` in `setProxyNamespace` method.

Comment: Have you tried trying to create an persist an entity and then load it again through it's repository?

Comment: i am expected problem is $classLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies',$lib1);
$classLoader->register();

Comment: Is this on your localhost? Can you confirm that you have APC installed?

Comment: OK Thank Apc error is Clear .Getting Another error.just update my question...

Comment: That is not a great practice to go spam on other questions to drag people here.

Comment: Downvoted for spamming other questions. Not cool

Answer (score 1):

It is not a solution but you could try using the commandline tool doctrine.php to generate proxies

> php doctrine.php orm:generate-proxies

Maybe you can locate the problem from here

Comment: no.here already generated entities ...

Comment: Error::Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'MyProject\Entities\Dept': Error: Class 'MyProject\Entities\Dept' is not defined.

Comment: Can you give us some more information about the entity code and directory structure you are using?

Comment: addded my entities dept code here?

Comment: It seems like you haven't declared a namespace in your entity code, should be something like `namespace MyProject\Enitities` above your class decleration

Comment: where  exact replace namespace MyProject\Enitities?

Comment: Place `namespace MyProject\Entities;` above the comment about the class

Comment: i am trying but getting same error here..if u don't mind send me your configuration code to mail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line with:

```
$classLoader = new ClassLoader('Entities',$lib1);
```

should be:

```
$classLoader = new ClassLoader('MyProject\Entities',$lib1);
```

Because the first parameter is a namespace of autoloaded classes.